# Google Calendar API freeBusy multiple calendars

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have successfully been able to get freeBusy data from a single calendar using PHP, but when I try to get multiple calendars in one call as suggested by Google:

```
"items": 
  [
    {
      "id": string
    }
  ]
```

I can't seem to use PHP to make the array object correct as I have tried the few examples on StackOverflow and my general skills on handling PHP arrays without success. The purpose is to have multiple calendar id's as an array, an then loop throug that array to make the request object correct according to Google API. Has anyone seen the same problem and **actually tried to use multiple** calendar id's. I have a slight feeling that this might be a bug in the PHP SDK for Google Calendar. Can anyone point in any direction? This is my working code for a single calendar id:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig("credentials/oauth-credentials.json");
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');

$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = 'narvik.kommune.no_2d37393134@resource.calendar.google.com';
//$calendarId = array('narvik.kommune.no_37383343730@resource.calendar.google.com','narvik.kommune.no_2d1383134@resource.calendar.google.com');
$freebusy_req = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequest();
$freebusy_req->setTimeMin(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime('2017-05-01T08:00:00.000Z')));
$freebusy_req->setTimeMax(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime('2017-05-19T17:00:00.000Z')));
$freebusy_req->setTimeZone($timezone);
$freebusy_req->setCalendarExpansionMax(10);
$freebusy_req->setGroupExpansionMax(10);

$item = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem();
$item->setId($calendarId);
$freebusy_req->setItems(array($item));
$query = $cal->freebusy->query($freebusy_req);

$response_calendar = $query->getCalendars();
$busy_obj = $response_calendar[$calendarId]->getBusy();
```

and this is the resulting print_r($busy_obj);

```
Array
(
[0] => Google_Service_Calendar_TimePeriod Object
    (
        [end] => 2017-05-01T14:50:00Z
        [start] => 2017-05-01T09:00:00Z
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )
    )
```

Comment: also thanks for your post! I was looking everywhere how to use Google's new PHP calendar library. Where did you find how to use `Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequest` and `Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like below.

```
$item = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem();
$item->setId($calendarId);
$item2 = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem();
$item2->setId($calendarId2);
$freebusy_req->setItems(array($item, $item2));
```

Basically you just need to create another `Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem` and comma separate the items in array() for the two calendar items.